# Изменение названия проекта на Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Прохожу обучение по одному курсу по Django. Там показывают, что ради удобства меняют название проекта. Например, создали проект на Django под названием: lamp, внутри автоматически создается подпапка lamp. И они просто меняют название проекта с lamp на lamp-project. Да, согласен, удобно, но теперь проект не запускается, так как пути к другим файлам исказились. Но у них всё нормально. Как так получилось?

P.S. Я делаю на Windows в Pycharm, на курсе делают в MacOS в Atom.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О каких искажённых путях речь?

Comment: Добавил скриншот из PyCharm

Comment: Скриншот намекает, что вы где-то зачем-то изменили DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, чего делать совершенно не нужно было

Comment: Нашел свою проблему. Когда меняю название проекта в Pycharm, то он меняет его везде. Для этого нужно отключить галочки: Search for references и Search in comments and strings. Далее сделать операцию migrate: python manage.py migrate. После этого всё работает нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно меняют название внутренней папки с настройками проекта на `config/`, нежели переименовывают головную, потому-что если переименовать основную папку проекта `lamp/` в `lamp-project/`, то это никак не повлияет на сами пути, всё будет работать. У вас получится папка `lamp-project/`, а в ней будет находится файл `manage.py` и папка `lamp/` с настройками. Скорее всего, вы переименовали внутреннюю папку `lamp/` с конфигурационными настройками в `lamp-project/`, тогда всё логично, что ваш проект перестал работать.

Теперь необходимо либо перенастроить свой проект, либо вернуть внутренней папке с настройками старое название. Для того чтобы  перенастроить проект, необходимо поочередно зайти в файлы и поменять старое название **lamp** на новое **lamp-project**. Начинаем с `settings.py`:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'lamp-project.urls' 

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lamp-project.wsgi.application'
```

`asgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'lamp-project.settings')
```

`wsgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'lamp-project.settings')
```

теперь меняем настройки в самом файле `manage.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'lamp-project.settings')
```

как по мне это  вкусовщина, но лучше уже тогда менять название на более понятное **config**, чем на **lamp-project**.

А так в `PyCharm` есть поиск по проекту, с помощью которого можно переименовать всё в автоматическом режиме, а не бегать по файлам и не  править всё ручками, но это, как по мне, для "слабаков". С `Atom` я не знаком, но предполагаю, что там тоже есть подобный функционал.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ. Как я изменил название, добавил скриншотом в сам вопрос